# Passing generic DC load through USB pin on BQ2403 IC

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit, lipo

I'm looking at [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24032a.pdf?ts=1689202149583&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ24032A) (BQ2403) Li-po charging IC and am wondering if there is any reason I couldn't pass a 4.2v DC load through the USB pin instead of straight USB. I feel like this is dumb, but I'm also not sure why they would specify that the pin is for USB over a generic Vin pin.

If this wouldn't work, is there a simple way to pass a DC load into it?

Pardon my extreme ineptitude surrounding this topic, I'm very new to electronics and am way out of my comfort zone in terms of what I know.

[image: BQ2403 Diagram]